# Configure SQLFluff rules

Tags: sql, postgresql, dbt, sqlfluff

I use SQLFluff to ensure a uniform syntax in the company and reduce error warnings before running the models in dbt. Since our syntax does not completely match the syntax of SQLFluff I would like to make some changes.

The [Rules References](https://docs.sqlfluff.com/en/stable/rules.html) provided by SQLFluff helped me to set up *Inline Ignoring Errors*, as displayed in the code below (last line of code).

So I have two questions, which I was not able to answer also with the help of the Rules References of SQLFluff.

1. I would like to set Rule *L032* as default 'false' without typing it manually every time in my SQL.
2. How do I change the maximal length of a line regarding Rule *L016*? I would like to set the default value e.g. 150.

[image: Rule_L016]

```
SELECT
    country.country_name,
    country.population,
    currency.currency_name,
    currency.currency_id,
    currency.strange_long_variable_name_which_is_too_long as not_so_long_variable_name
FROM country
LEFT JOIN currency
    USING (country) -- noqa: L032
```

I tried to figure it out with the [Rules References](https://docs.sqlfluff.com/en/stable/rules.html) but could not figure it out. Help is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With the help of [@suhprano](https://stackoverflow.com/users/435228/suhprano)'s answer, I was able to find the proper solution for my issue. For this reason, I will post an answer to my own question. I do this intending to provide others assistant with similar issues.

I created the .sqlfluff file in my user profile folder. In this file I have then included the following:

```
[sqlfluff]
exclude_rules = L032
[sqlfluff:rules]
max_line_length = 150
```

In this case, SQLFluff will load the configuration from any .sql file found at the path specified on this variable.

Comment: Hi Albin, i have tried the creating .sqlfluff file to exclude few rules, but after using lint command still the rules are not excluded and displaying the error or warnings for those rules, could you please where we need to keep the .sqlfluff file so that rules will be excluded

Comment: @Albin The exclude_rules part isn't working for me either.

Comment: What is the syntax for sqlfluff 2.x ?

Answer (score 0):

Just an addition to the answer:
The default config of the rules can be found inside the package in file `core\default_config.cfg`

See also:

- https://github.com/sqlfluff/sqlfluff/blob/main/src/sqlfluff/core/default_config.cfg
- https://docs.sqlfluff.com/en/stable/configuration.html#defaultconfig

As already mentioned by @Albin the easiest way to override the config is to add a .sqlfluff file in the user profile folder.

See also:
https://docs.sqlfluff.com/en/stable/configuration.html#rule-configuration

Answer (score 0):

I figured out why SQLfluff wasn't applying the configuration I had written in the .sqlfluff file placed in my dbt root folder (we're using SQLfluff in combination with dbt).

SQLfluff will NOT apply the configuration if you are standing in a subfolder (current working directory) when giving the command, i.e. `sqlfluff lint my_file.sql`. As such you need to give the command from the root of the dbt project folder for it to work properly, i.e. `sqlfluff lint path_to_my_file`.

This happens due to the way SQLfluff searches for its configuration file (which is called nesting). Nesting: https://docs.sqlfluff.com/en/stable/configuration.html#new-project-configuration