# SQLFluff `exclude_rules` configuration ignored

Tags: sqlfluff

I have this in my .sqlfluff, as per SQLFluff's [documentation](https://docs.sqlfluff.com/en/stable/configuration.html):

```
[sqlfluff]
exclude_rules = L003
```

When I run `sqlfluff lint` in the same directory where the configuration file is located, it still checks rule L003. What am I missing to exclude it?

Comment: I had a similar issue.
I wrote the answer in this thread: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/77266158/11724411](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77266158/11724411)

Answer (score 0):

The rules to be excluded are comma-separated even when there is only one so you need to write:

```
[sqlfluff]
exclude_rules = L003,
```

Comment: I've added the comma but L003 still gets checked.